# Using an in-memory database within a gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubygems

I am writing a gem that does some complex parsing/composition of a plist file.

I thought it would make sense to use the ActiveRecord interface for this and build 'structures' as an in-memory database.

The gem works fine on its own. However, I'd like to be able to incorporate it into a Rails project. The problem is that my gem calls establish_conneciton on ActiveRecord::Base which kills any previous connection the Rails app had.

It does seem to be possible because there's a section in the ActiveRecord::Base documentation titled: [Connection to multiple databases in different models](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base)

This implies you can subclass from ActiveRecord::Base and call establish_connection on that. The problem then is that you can't define your schema because ActiveRecord::Schema.define uses the connection currently set on Base.

I'm thinking that the only way to do this may be to build the tables into the Rails app the includes the gem. I'd rather not go down that route if I can help it though. Any ideas?

You can view the database setup file for my gem [here](https://github.com/cpatuzzo/xteam_schedule/blob/master/lib/xteam_schedule/facilitation/db.rb), if I've not made myself clear.

Many thanks

Comment: any change to override the establish_connection ? and let it do nothing?

Comment: Most gems that require you have certain tables in your database have the user create those tables. I think it'd be very bad taste to go about creating tables on a whim in the app's database. (Unless, perhaps, if they're temporary tables)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. Andrew Marshall: In this case, my tables are temporary and intended for in-memory use only.

I figured out a solution that may be of use to anyone who stumbles upon this:
[Switching connection on ActiveRecord::Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743007/switching-connection-on-activerecordschema/9592667#9592667)

Thanks again.